# validate dropdown selection with a object in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I validate the selected item without having to duplicate the CompanyId in the EmployeeViewModel?

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public CompanyViewModel Company { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Company, Model.Companies, "-- Choose One --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Company)
```

I was expecting to be something like that.

I know that if I change the Company into a CompanyId int it'll work fine but then I have to fetch the Company by my self.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.CompanyId, Model.Companies, "-- Choose One --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.CompanyId)
```

Am I missing something in the first approach?

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object, and your view model needs to contain a property `int? CompanyId` (and your `CompanyViewModel Company` should be removed especially since it will always result in a `ModelState` error in the POST method.

Comment: And your `Model.Companies` in the `DropDownList` does not work either (it needs to be a property which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`)